# Set select field options conditionally based on prior select field value

Tags: keystonejs

I'm using this data as an example, but in Keystone is there a way to set the options of a select field depending on a prior select field?

For example, if I have a selected a state, in the next select after it where it asks for the city, it would populate the options with the cities depending on the chosen state.

Is there a way to write an if...else statment or some way to do this without creating a bunch of city fields (oregonCities, washingtonCities, idahoCities, etc etc for all 50 states)

something like this:

```
  state: {
    type: Types.Select,
    options: 'Oregon, Washington'
  },
  city: {
    type: Types.Select,

    //if state selected is oregon use these options
    dependsOn: { state: 'Oregon' },
    options: 'Portland, Bend, Salem'

    //if state selected is washington use these options
    dependsOn: { state: 'Washington' },
    options: 'Seattle, Olympia, Spokane'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible in current version, but you can add this as feature request for next version in alpha stage. github - https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-5

Comment: there must be a workaround - what i'm doing currently is i just create a bunch of city fields (oregonCity, washingtonCity, etc) then show them using dependsOn, but its not ideal. also, i think they want to use canny for feature requests. there is currently a feature request open: https://keystonejs.canny.io/feature-requests/p/allow-the-values-of-select-fields-to-be-generated-dynamically

Comment: That workaround has to be added in the admin ui code, KeystoneJs v4 is in maintenance mode. don't expect any new features there